# How do I move only selected meshes?

Tags: modeling, mesh, scale

I am currently modeling a type of gun known as the Scar-L. I am having trouble with this though, I extruded a piece out that will later connect to the magazine.

[image: Red and blue lines]

As you can see, I want the selected orange lines to scale, based on the y axis, down to reach the blue lines. I have tried this by selecting the sides faces, pressing s, then y, but it will stretch. Like shown in this picture:

[image: Without red and blue lines]

I am trying to figure out how to avoid that and only scale inwards the selected meshes and not the entire thing. Any help would be appreciated! :D

Comment: Those bottom faces can't be scaled independently of the top faces as they are connected and hence will move together. Either rip them apart, scale and close the gaps or change the design

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, Please try this:

Select your source faces:

[image]

Hit **E and S** (E for extrude and S for scale) and drag mouse inside to scale

You will get some thing like this:

[image]

You also lock the scale to y if you like by hitting **Y** after S
Final command will be **E and S and Y**

[image]

Best of luck :)